# Bind Label to class' property

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding

I'm trying to bind a label (NSTextField) to a class' property. In **Interface Builder** I bind the label's **Value** to *File's Owner* with **Model Key Path** = *self.aString*.

- *File's Owner* is a NSViewController's subclass with *aString* defined as: `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *aString;`
- The label is placed inside a **View Based NSTableView** filled at run-time by a binding with a managed object context.

When i call `[self setAString:@"..."]` or `[self setValue:@"..." forKey:@"aString"]` in the class' implementation, nothing changes in the table view. However if the label is placed inside the view it works. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by **subclassing NSTableCellView** and **adding to it a NSString property**. Then i bound the value of the label to the Table Cell View with the name of the property as key.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of view-based table views, and from what I know the only way to fix it would be to set `TableView.delegate` to your `File's Owner` (or another object if you're trying to bind to that instead).

*(I'm hoping for a better answer to explain why, because I don't know why this is the case)*

Cake's answer is a good workaround.

Comment: Setting the delegate to File's Owner causes the error:  *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Comment: I decided to upvote your answer because it looks like this guy isn't coming back.

Comment: @user1471997 I was reviewing some of my old answers and found this question again. Have you fixed this issue? (and I may be too late to ask, but where is the error showing up? Can you update your question with the entire stack?)

Answer (score -1):

You probably don't have direct access to it when it's inside the tableview. Try storing a reference to the tableview and then calling the label. So if your table had a reference named t, connect the label to the table and then:
`t.labelName.text = @"string"` Although, if it's inside a cell in the table you may need to use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and reference the label inside a subclassed cell. If you don't know how to do this I can post some code.